# Encrypting using user's password

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, encryption

I want to encrypt a given data using the log-in user's password on a windows machine using WINAPI. I've been looking for a function that uses a token (or something like that) but I couldn't find one.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Just to make this clear: you want to eventually be able to recover the data you're encrypting right? You're not trying to store the user's password, but to use it to derive an encryption key, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had written this answer earlier but then reconsidered, since I hadn't heard of the DPAPI before. However, upon some further consideration, I'd like to offer the following opinion. The important preface here is that it all depends on your needs, though. Two conflicting possibilities come to mind:

1. You want to offer your *user* complete protection and encryption that the user can trust only she will be able to decrypt, no matter the circumstances.
2. You're an enterprise IT manager and have all employees on a tight leash. You want them to encrypt business data as part of their workflow so that they cannot see each other's data, but the admins can happily read everyone's data.

If you're in situation (2), then stop reading now and go with DPAPI, which is well suited to that case. If you prefer scenario (1), then read my original answer below.

---

That's probably not a good idea. Here's why:

The actual password will not be stored on the system (unless you have Windows 3.11 or something like that). Instead, only a hash of the password will be stored, and at login time the password that the user enters is hashed and compared to the stored hash.

So at best you could retrieve the stored hash from the system (if you have admin rights, say). However, if that's the only datum you can go on, then any encryption key you make will be derived from that hash, rather than from the actual password. Thus anyone with access to the system could get to the stored hash, and from there derive the encryption key with relative ease.

In short, don't. Ask the user for a dedicated, fresh password for your data and use it for only that.

Comment: You can use the DPAPI and still ask the user for a dedicated password. That's what the optional entropy parameter in CryptProtectData is for.

Comment: Yes, but the OP appears to want to use the login password specifically. Granted, you can use DPAPI as the implementation of (1).

Comment: Agreed. And let me put some emphasis your last paragraph: ask for a **dedicated** password, not the logon password, and make that clear. Please don't train users to type their existing passwords anywhere they're asked.

Comment: Hehe - yes, in an ideal world :-) Though you're on thin ice, would you rather reuse passwords or have a post-it with all your unique passwords under your keyboard? Are your reused passwords stored in a LeetBlogz plain-text database? What a minefield...

Answer (score 8):

The [Windows Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) sounds like what you need. The [CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261.aspx) functions perform encryption using the logon credentials of the current user.

Comment: I'm wondering: Can an admin on the system recover enough information to "unprotect" data that was protected by any user on the system? The article says that the credential is essentially just a password hash.

Comment: @Kerrek: It uses the logon credentials. The optional entropy parameter is well, optional. An admin can impersonate anyone, but the DPAPI does not work under impersonation (I had to give up on using it before because of this). It could be coaxed to work, but it takes some effort.

Comment: I mean a bit more low-level: Since the encryption is just some well-known cipher using the password hash as a key, an admin could just retrieve all the hashes from the system and decrypt the blobs directly, non?

Comment: @Kerrek: As usual, the answer is yes, they can, it depends on how much effort they are willing to put into it. The optional entropy gives you another layer of protection.

Comment: @Martinho, Just to understand it better, does EFS uses the *hash* of the password to encrypt? If so, I must admit that I'm a bit amazed.

Comment: @TCS: EFS uses a per-user key-pair to protect the symmetric key used for encryption. In newer versions of Windows (starting with Vista, I think) you can save this private key externally. In any case this key-pair has to be stored somewhere in the system, so admins will definitely have access to it.

Comment: @Martinho: But how do they keep/store the private key? They still need somekind of a password/key to keep it encrypted on the disk (It all gets connected to the reason I asked the question). p.s. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @TCS: Yes, it is stored on the disk. Yes, EFS is not the greatest thing in terms of cryptographic safety.

Comment: @Martinho: Okay, got my answer :-) Thank!

Answer (score 0):

use Kerberos (Linux-based authentication server, or other servers using Kerberos) / LDAP framework (Windows server) instead of designing your own login algorithm.

Windows Platform SDK & 3rd-party libraries have connectors with these frameworks.

More information in MSDN about Kerberos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649429.aspx

Answer (score -1):

[How to safely store a password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)

Win32 bcrypt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The question asks about encrypting data, not storing passwords.