How to prevent the password to be shown as plain text in the WindowsImpersonate using c#?
I created a class that will implement Windows impersonate at the constructor and have the other functions only execute when _logonSuccess is true.
The purpose of the functions in this class is to get information about Event Viewer on another PC for specific applications.
See the section of the code below:
namespace project
{
        public class MyProjectClass
        {
            // P/Invoke for LogonUser
            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword,
                int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern int GetLastError();

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int FormatMessage(uint dwFlags,IntPtr lpSource,uint dwMessageId,uint dwLanguageId,StringBuilder lpBuffer,uint nSize,IntPtr Arguments);

            private const uint FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER = 0x00000100;
            private const uint FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x00001000;
            private const uint FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS = 0x00000200;
            
            IntPtr tokenHandle;
            private string _domain;
            private string _username;
            private string _password;       
            private string _user;
            private string _pass;
            private string _domn;
        
            public MyProjectClass()
            {
                _rsaEnc = new RSAEncryption(filepath); // filepath -> json file that will have the required information for the impersonate function

                bool domainVer = DomainVerification();
                
                if (domainVer)
                {
                    _domain = ReadInfo("Domain"); // ReadInfo looks at json file used for configuration
                    _username = ReadInfo("Username");
                    _password = ReadInfo("Password");

                    string domain = _rsaEnc.Decrypt(_domain);
                    string user = _rsaEnc.Decrypt(_username);
                    string pass = _rsaEnc.Decrypt(_password);

                    _domn = domain;
                    _user = user;
                    _pass = pass;

                    tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                    _logonSuccess = LogonUser(user, domain, pass, 9, 3, out tokenHandle);
                }
                else
                {
                    _domain = "";
                    _username = ReadInfo("Username");
                    _password = ReadInfo("Password");

                    string domain = _domain;
                    string user = _rsaEnc.Decrypt(_username);
                    string pass = _rsaEnc.Decrypt(_password);

                    IntPtr tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                    _logonSuccess = LogonUser(user, domain, pass, 9, 3, out tokenHandle);
                }

                if (!_logonSuccess)
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    string errorMessage = GetErrorMessage(errorCode);
                    _logWriter.LogWrite($"LogonUser failed with error code: {errorCode}; Error Message: {errorMessage}", this.GetType().Name, "LoginAccess", MessageLevels.Fatal, DebugLevel.True);
                }
            }



    static string GetErrorMessage(int errorCode)
    {
        StringBuilder messageBuffer = new StringBuilder(512);
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,IntPtr.Zero,(uint)errorCode,0,messageBuffer,(uint)messageBuffer.Capacity,IntPtr.Zero);

        return messageBuffer.ToString();
    }

So, my issue is that the password is stored on private variable but as plain text (after decryption). What would I need to do to prevent the application of exposing the password as plain text during runtime?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318368/encrypting-using-users-password

You mean you don't want to have it as decrypted string in Memory at any time?

@HansPassant Thank you for the reply, I will have a look at the link. I have a question, can the advapi32 for LogOnUser use like SecureString or something instead of using string?

@Ralf, Yes. That is what I am aiming for and also if you can see the question that I asked HansPassant.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850342/using-securestring-with-logonuser

@HansPassant, Thank you. I was able to resolve it with the link that you provided.

Note that Microsoft has thrown in the towel on SecureString, admitting that it doesn't really provide true security  https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md or read the note here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-security-securestring
